# getFormAction() returns empty string

Tags: php, forms, magento

I am embedding the contacts form onto a CMS page with this bit of layout XML:

```
<reference name="content">
<block type="core/template" name="cmsContactForm" form_action="/contacts/index/post" template="contacts/form.phtml"></block>
</reference>
```

However, when I am on that CMS page this bit of code on the contacts form page:

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->getFormAction(); ?>" id="contactForm" method="post">
```

The `getFormAction()` method returns an empty string, resulting in the contact form failing as it just refreshes the page instead of submitting the information in the contact form.

Can anyone tell me how to get a proper form action from `getFormAction()`?

Is there a relevant helper that I can employ on a CMS page?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<form action="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('contacts/index/post', array('_secure' => $this->getRequest()->isSecure())); ?>" id="contactForm" method="post">
```